# Open pyramid flower-like by rotating its faces

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, polygons

I'm trying to animate a pyramid (with any base) opening its lateral faces like a flower. I found the best way to this to be the Rotate function.

The problem is, I have no clue how it works. I have read the documentation page and tried some simple examples but every time the rotation I end up with seems completely random to me.

The pyramid has its center in the origin and it's built with the following function:

```
    myPyramid[edges_, open_] := (
    points = Map[Append[#, 0] &, CirclePoints[edges]];
    apex = {0, 0, 2};
    base = Polygon[points];
    points = Append[points, points[[1]]];
    faces = Partition[points, 2, 1];
    {Map[Rotate[ Polygon[Join[#, {apex}]], 
    open Degree, #[[2]] , #[[1]]] &, faces], base}
  )
```

Since I need to rotate a Polygon around its base I though the function I was looking for was

> Rotate[g,θ,w,p]
>   rotates around the 3D vector w anchored at p.

However the result is not what I was looking for; the faces detach from the base and start rotating around a vertex.

```
    Manipulate[Graphics3D[myPyramid[5, x],
      Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 3}}], {x, 0, 90}]
```

[image: my opened pyramid]

Can anyone please explain to me how does Rotate works in 3D and/or how to rotate said faces the way I want?

Comment: You need `#[[2]] - #[[1]]` as the 3rd argument to Rotate

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly as I intended it. Can you explain me why? I can't understand exactly why I have to subtract the vectors of the edge I want it to rotate around

Comment: You have specified each edge by the points at either end `{p, q}`. The vector you want to rotate around runs *from* p *to* q, and that vector is given by `q - p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Simon's comment, everything I needed to do was to use the vector `#[[2]] -#[[1]]` as third argument. My final result is:

```
myPyramid[edges_, 
 open_] := (points = Map[Append[#, 0] &, CirclePoints[edges]];
 apex = {0, 0, 2};
 base = Polygon[points];
 points = Append[points, points[[1]]];
 faces = Partition[points, 2, 1];
 {Map[Rotate[Polygon[Join[#, {apex}]], 
    open Degree, #[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[1]]] &, faces], base})

Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[myPyramid[faces, x], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 3}}], {faces, 
  Range[3, 12]}, {x, 0, 110} ]
```

Which leads to the animation I wanted:

[image: Flower pyramid]

As Simon said,

> You have specified each edge by the points at either end {p, q}. The vector you want to rotate around runs from p to q, and that vector is given by q - p

Answer (score 3):

To rotate, it's better to remove box lines and axes.

If you wan to animate it, you can replace Manipulate with Animate in the code.

In:

```
myPyramid[edges_, open_] := Module[{points, apex, base, faces, rotate},
  points = Map[Append[#, 0] &, CirclePoints[edges]];
  apex = {0, 0, 2};
  base = Polygon[points];
  points = Append[points, points[[1]]];
  faces = Partition[points, 2, 1];
  rotate = 
   Rotate[Polygon[Join[#, {apex}]], open Degree, #[[2]], #[[1]]] &;
   {faces // Map[rotate], base}]


Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[myPyramid[5, x], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 3}},
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[x 90/(2 Pi), {0, 0, 1}][{3, 0, 3}]],
 {x, 0, 90}]
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: A good answer, but it would be better were you to localize variables in `myPyramid`; i.e., `myPyramid[edges_, open_] := Module[{points, apex, base, faces}, ... ]`. I can see that you just copied the OP's function, but I am recommending to take the opportunity to show the OP how to improve it.

Comment: Thanks, I have localized variables.

Comment: That is not what I wanted. I wanted the lateral faces to open up rotating around their bases, not to add a viewpoint rotation. Simon's comment answered me, but I still want to understand how/why it works. +1 for the `Module` usage example, though, it was helpful.